# How do I return the response from an asynchronous call inside an angularjs service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have already read the answers to the question [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) But I'm not sure I understood it well and I think that my problem is a bit different. I change my service in this way:

```
.service('CommonService',['$firebase', function($firebase){

var username;

function onComplete(result){
    username = result;
};

var getData = function(){

    var ref = new Firebase("https://instafame.firebaseio.com");

    ref.onAuth(function(authData){
        var userid = authData.uid;
        console.log(userid);

        var newref = new Firebase("https://instafame.firebaseio.com/users/" + userid)

        newref.once("value", function(snapshot) { 
            var data = snapshot.val()
            newUsername = data.username;
            callback(newUsername);

        })
    });
  };

    return{
        getUsername: function(){
            getData(onComplete);
            return username;}
    };
}])
```

In my controller I store inside a variable `user` the return of the `CommonService`:

```
var user = CommonService.getUsername();
console.log(user);
```

**The problem is that the console still returns "undefined"**. I have tried to change the code following the suggestions but it doesn't run. What should I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have all these callbacks, trying to accomplish the impossible.

Comment: Make `getData` and `getUsername` return a promise, not take a callback.

Comment: @Bergi I'm so ignorant can you be more explicit in the code?

Comment: I am wondering what  `callback(newUsername); ` is. Is `callback()` defined somewhere?

Comment: It looks like you need to provide 'callback' as an argument for your `getData()` definition.

Answer (score 1):

> Async / Await

We need to provide a way to wait for a response from your requests. We can use async/await to do this and lets make a Promise to handle resolving the value we are retrieving;

```
.service('CommonService',['$firebase', function($firebase){

var username;
var getData = function(){     //declare this function as an async

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 

        var ref = new Firebase("https://instafame.firebaseio.com");

        ref.onAuth(function(authData){
            var userid = authData.uid;
            console.log(userid);

            var newref = new Firebase("https://instafame.firebaseio.com/users/" + userid)

            newref.once("value", function(snapshot) { 
                var data = snapshot.val()
                newUsername = data.username;
                !!newUsername 
                    ?
                resolve(newUsername)
                    :
                reject('Error: No username found');
            })

       });
    };
 };

    return{
        getUsername: async function(){
            username = await getData(); //await will pause execution of the code here until getData() returns a value.
            return username;
        }
    };
}])
```

Comment: You don't need to declare `getData` as `async` - it already explicitly returns a new Promise - but you need to do so at the `getUsername` function where you use `await`, so that it returns a promise as well.

Comment: Currently, we cannot use await without first declaring the containing function as an async function. This might change in a the up coming ECMA update but until then, we need async for await. 

Also you can shorten the getUsername method to
 `getUsername: function(){
                return await getData(); 
            }`

Comment: Yes, exactly. And your code doesn't follow these rules - the function that contains `await` is not declared `async`